# Peak TX current of LoRa RFM95W

Tags: batteries, lora, brownout

I'm running into some issues powering a test board using a LoRa chip (RFM95W) with a CR2032 battery. I'm well aware of the peak current limitation of such battery and I can see a major voltage drop across the battery when too much current is asked during LoRa TX (around 80mA), even using a 100uF capacitor in parallel; the voltage drops down below 1.5v which make my MCU brown-out and reset. Thus entering an infinite loop as my MCU is setup to send a measurement on start-up. I'm using a power gating timer (TPL5110) in order to minimise the current consumption between measurements, 1 mesure every two hours.

The question is: how do people manage to use CR2032 coin cell battery alongside LoRa RFM95W as I assume the peak TX current would be fairly similar in all these other IOT boards I can see around internet. I'm using default firmware mode of communication under LoRa-WAN standard of The Things Network and my support hardware around the RFM95W does not account for more than 5mA of current.

I'm not sure my question if well formulated, but mainly I'm looking for any advices on how to use a CR battery and still manage to power my device. In the meanwhile I'm also looking at replacing by 2x AAA battery, but space is precious.

Thank you for your time you might take to answer.

Answer (score 1):

To be blunt, that's really not a great idea, as the current demand is far in excess of what a coin cell can supply.

Typically sensors are designed to run for a long time, and so will use higher capacity cells, which are typically able to support proportionately higher peak loads as well.

If you really want to try to design something that can achieve a very short number of transmissions off an undersized battery, you probably need to use a large capacitor to provide the transmit current.  But realize that packets of hundred of milliseconds are common (or well over a second in Europe), so that's going to be a fairly large capacitor.  You may even want to go so far as to to have MCU logic which pre-charges the capacitor only in preparation for a transmission - typically the packet duration ends up being calculated anyway, so you could anticipate the overall energy requirement and factor that into the preparation.

Comment: As I mention, while I understand fully the reasons and how this is not a great idea. I'm still wondering how/why there are so many projects using the same LoRa hardware based on CR2032. Which originally gave me the idea to design around a CR2032 battery.

Comment: Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0xt7RwphoA

Comment: A video link is not engineering documentation.  If a project meets your goal, study its actual engineering documentation.  Likely you will find what it is doing is similar in one way or another to what is proposed here.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at my CR2032 equivalent circuit below can you spot your issue?

What is your equivalent load current?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbixqA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Battery ESR is generally inverse with mAh rating in all batteries but differs for Lithium, Li-Ion, Alkaline, AGM etc.

Battery ESR also rises rapidly after 80% DoD until drained. then it is > 100x fresh ESR.

I did not bother to model the effective capacitance for the mAh and V rating but this can also be done or define its equivalent storage charge Q or stored energy E to cutoff.

Z load needs to be > 300 Ohms to minimize drop to 10% unless there is a large storage cap in theory. **In practice, choose a bigger battery with lower ESR.**

Answer (score 1):

suppose you need to store a watt-second of energy.

2 farad at 1 volt will work

or 0.02farad at 10 volts

or 0.002  farad at 31 volts

its your choice

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

1. As suggested already, placing a capacitor in parallel to the MCU, and selecting its size based on the duration of the pulse. You need to ensure the energy DIFFERENCE between start-finish charge is sufficient. With a nominal voltage of the CR2032 at 3.0V, and the MCU restart voltage of 2.7V you have very little energy difference, so a really large capacitor might be needed.
2. Boost the capacitor voltage to store larger energy. This, however, requires 2 voltage converter and might mess up the quiescent current.
3. You could try breaking up the transmission into several smaller segments so that each pulse requires a smaller charge from the capacitors. (the 100uF cap might not be sufficient though.)
4. You could try using the LoRa module at a lower transmit power, in case range is not a problem.
5. The last thing I could think of is replacing the CR battery with more powerful batteries which allow larger pulse current.

Comment: One problem with breaking up a transmission is that typical protocols impose a fair amount of framing - something like 13 bytes for LoRaWAN between header and checksum.  So breaking up the transmission is going to result in repeating that framing, decreasing the power efficiency.